# Is it possible to make different-sized ticks for graphs?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, axis

Let's say that I have a graph an axis with 25 ticks, and I want to make every fifth tick (0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25) bigger than the other ticks to make reading the graph easier. (There is already number labels on those ticks and no labels on the other ticks, but reading is still rather uncomfortable...) Is it even possible? And what if I have, say, 27 ticks instead of 25?

E: A bit more information:

I'm actually editing a not-too-much-commented script made by a more experienced programmer (and I'm not very experienced). The program draws a color map (implying strain in coordinate point (x,y)) according to given data... uh, I have to admit that I don't understand all that is said in the code. But, there is the part in with the asked strain field is drawn.

```
        # Strain field on background
        fig = mpl.figure(1,figsize=(6,5),facecolor='w',edgecolor='k')
        mpl.clf()
        ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.5*(1-0.50*ratio)+0.05, 0.45, 0.50*ratio, 0.50])
        mpl.contourf(strainY.T * 100,50) # Into percents
        mpl.xlim(0,x-1)
        mpl.ylim(0,y-1)
        mpl.gca().invert_yaxis()
        yt = np.linspace(0,y-1,len(vHeight)+1)
        locs, labels = mpl.yticks(yt, vHeight, fontsize=9)
        xt = np.linspace(0,x-1,len(vWidth)+1)
        locs, labels = mpl.xticks(xt, vWidth, fontsize=9)
```

yt and xt mean special vectors that are used for placing the ticks. Due some annoying scaling stuff (from pixels (?) to other measurements) and varying lengths of axes, they need some work... anyway, the result is a 2D strain map where is ticks with constant spaces...

Ask more if you need more information, I'm that confused that I don't know what information is necessary.

...what I have understood below comments and documentations, contourf() corresponds plot(). So set_major_locator should work? Though I remember I tried it once, it didn't turn out well... I can try it again in a copy of that script, though.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for major and minor ticks? I assume you are looking for the following example:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html#pylab-examples-major-minor-demo1

**Edit**
I've adapted your example so it can be run. Next time, please post a minimal example which someone else can copy/paste/execute.

From the website cited above I've copied the axis formatting. If I understand your question correctly, you wish to set tick marks at arbitrary locations. For this, we can use the FixedLocator with a list. If you have constant intervals between ticks, then use the MultipleLocator. There are a ton of other Locators in matplotlib.ticker...

You should be able to run the code below and hopefully get what you want! :-)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter, FixedLocator

majorLocator   = FixedLocator([0,15,19,40,60,99])
majorFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%d')
minorLocator   = MultipleLocator(5)

ratio = 1
strainY = np.zeros((100,100))
x = 100
y = 100
vHeight = np.arange(0,100,5)
vWidth = np.arange(0,100,5)

# Strain field on background
fig = mpl.figure(1,figsize=(6,5),facecolor='w',edgecolor='k')
mpl.clf()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.5*(1-0.50*ratio)+0.05, 0.45, 0.50*ratio, 0.50])
mpl.contourf(strainY.T * 100,50) # Into percents
mpl.xlim(0,x-1)
mpl.ylim(0,y-1)
mpl.gca().invert_yaxis()
yt = np.linspace(0,y-1,len(vHeight)+1)
locs, labels = mpl.yticks(yt, vHeight, fontsize=9)
xt = np.linspace(0,x-1,len(vWidth)+1)
locs, labels = mpl.xticks(xt, vWidth, fontsize=9)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)

mpl.show()
```

If this is not what you need, could you please change your example code to something that runs, and perhaps post a sketch of what it is you need?

Comment: Ah, this seems promising! Thank you, I'll check it.

Comment: ...uh, well, seems that I can't use it in my case. My script makes separately axes for the image, they can't be made with plotting due some scaling etc. stuff... anyway. The axis ticks are currently made in this way: `locs, labels = mpl.yticks(yt, vHeight)` where yt tells the locations of the ticks and vHeight tells what come to the labels. That' the only good way to deal it that I know. I'm not sure how to put set_major_locator and stuff in my case... can someone advice? I tried to read documentation of matplotlib.ticker, but I can't find help... I'm not very experienced with this stuff.

Comment: @mmyntti: I guess you'd have to provide some more info as to why the usual major/minor ticks do not suffice. The best would be to have a minimal example script which shows the problem.

Comment: Ah! Sorry about forgetting that "write in executable form" thing. I'm pretty new there. I'll check that ticking issue and fix that above written code as soon as I get another project away from hands. Thanks a bunch, and sorry about messing that much!

Comment: No problem, hopefully you get it to work! If my answer does not match your question, please let me know.

Comment: Uh... I tried this, but there is some scaling stuff in my script that makes this MajorMinorTicking very painful... unfortunately it looks like that I have to give up until I learn using matplotlib better. I don't understand all in the script, and it's that large script that it's most likely pain to read it here as whole. I think that I'll bookmark this page and return to the problem as I learn more about the issue (the problem is not fatal one). Thanks a lot anyway, now I can handle simpler case! Should I modify my post to concern a simpler case, since this site is a Q&A site?

Comment: I would argue that the combination of the current answer and question suffice. If someone wants major and minor ticks, then they can use Locators to place the major and minor ticks. Good luck with the rest of your challenges.

Comment: All right, so I keep this in current format, even if this is rather messy. And thanks!